# Staying over 90 days in Portugal, as any EU national and non-EU spouse

Tags: eu-spouses, portugal

I have a British passport. 
My wife is Japanese and has an indefinite leave to remain (she is currently awaiting  her British passport) - she has lived in UK for 15 years or more.
I also have a daughter with British passport.

We've stayed in Portugal for around 70 days. We're heading back to UK for 2 weeks and then will come back to Portugal for another 90 days.

I'm wondering is there likely to be any problem on re-entry to Portugal? I'm guessing there won't be (because I'm allowed up to 6 months before needing to register here and my wife (I'm hoping) assumes the same conditions as me (since we are married).

Answer (score 4):

You should not have any trouble.  You may be asked for documentation to show that your wife is in fact your wife, but as long as you have that, she enjoys a derivative right of freedom of movement.

In fact, because of that, the two of you can use the EU passports queue when you arrive in any Schengen port of entry, even if she is traveling with a non-EU passport.  This is explicit in the [Schengen borders code](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/LKD/?uri=celex:32006R0562).

Comment: Just careful that staying away from the UK for that long doesn't affect her getting a UK passport.